# Different model name gives `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` error in AutoModel.from_pretrained

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am training a multi-task model which does ner and text classification. But when I change the model name in AutoModel.from_pretrained it gives error. 
In the code below, the commented "self.model" doesn't give error and runs fine, but the "emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT" gives error following error:
**Error:**
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.

**Model code:**

```
class MultiTaskModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self,model_name=None,model_type='BERT',**kwargs):
    super(MultiTaskModel, self).__init__()

    self.model=AutoModel.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT") # model that causes the error.
    # self.model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('medicalai/ClinicalBERT') # this line works fine

    self.num_labels_ner=kwargs['num_labels_ner']
    self.num_labels_stat=kwargs['num_labels_status']
    #print(self.model.config)
    self.dropout=nn.Dropout(0.2)
    self.pre_classifier = torch.nn.Linear(self.model.config.hidden_size, 256)

    # Layers for NER

    self.linear_ner=nn.Linear(256,self.num_labels_ner)

    # Layers for status_time
    self.linear_status=nn.Linear(256,self.num_labels_stat)

  def forward(
        self,
        input_ids=None,
        attention_mask=None,
        head_mask=None,
        inputs_embeds=None,
        labels=None,
        output_attentions=None,
        output_hidden_states=None,
        return_dict=None,
    ):
      outputs=self.model(
            input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            head_mask=head_mask,
            inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,
            output_attentions=output_attentions,
            output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
            return_dict=return_dict)

      #print("Lengths of output ",len(outputs))
      sequence_output = outputs[0]
      #print(outputs[0].shape)
      # pooled_output = outputs[1]
      pooled_output = sequence_output[:,0,:]

      #for ner
      sequence_output=self.dropout(sequence_output)
      sequence_output=self.pre_classifier(nn.ReLU()(sequence_output))
      ner_out=self.dropout(sequence_output)
      ner_logits=self.linear_ner(ner_out)

      # for status_time
      pooled_output=self.pre_classifier(pooled_output)
      stat_out=self.dropout(pooled_output)

      stat_logits=self.linear_status(stat_out)
      # print("Stat_logits shape ",stat_logits.shape)

      return ner_logits,stat_logits
```